# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure - .net core 2.0 to AWS EB

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, iis, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm getting this error after deploying my API to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

**Steps to reproduce**

- File -> New -> Project
- ASP.NET Core Web Application
- ASP.NET Core 2.0
- Web API
- F5: OK
- Publish to AWS Elastic Beanstalk... (via AWS Tollkit for Visual Studio 2017)
- HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

**Additional info**

- Visual Studio 2017
- 64bit Windows Server 2012 R2 v1.2.0 running IIS 8.5

I've already tried looking up [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624453/asp-net-core-1-0-on-iis-error-502-5) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43902658/asp-net-core-web-app-http-error-502-5-process-failure-on-visual-studio-15-2) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114166/asp-net-core-2-0-preview-2-on-iis-error-502-5), but to no success.

---

[image: Error]
**Log**
2018-01-15T13:27:21.000Z Error 0:(0) IIS AspNetCore Module - Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\app\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\WebApplication2.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 8000808c.

Comment: How did you resolve that issue?

Comment: Personally, as answered below. But it seems there are other causes for this, with other solutions. I'd recommend looking up the other three links presented in the question body if that's your case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Adding the above code to the .csproj solved the problem.

Comment: life saver, seems limited to .net core 2 as it worked perfectly fine with old .net

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue. After contacting AWS support, it turns out that there was a bug in my code [Release version].

I suggest the following steps to debug locally:

1. Publish your solution to a file
2. Open Command Prompt in the published folder
3. Run "dotnet Your.Main.App.dll"
4. Most probably you will see an exception

Sometimes we forget to test our solutions in Release mode.

Cheers!